# Can a tableview have columns that take checkbox and image

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to create a component in QML as shown in the attached screenshot
[image]

AFAIK, TableView is the component that I should use to create something like this using QML. Looking at the example [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html) it seems that it can support multiple columns and the style is configurable. However, I am not sure how to add the checkbox control and an image element in the columns.

Comment: I think you need to implement a custom delegate to achieve this. I'd employ a list view and use the said delegate with that view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will look into it and update!

Comment: @iksemyonov Managed to get the checkboxes to show and I am sure the image should be similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853791/qml-tableview-with-checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from here:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Window {
    visible: true

    width:1000; height: 500

    ListModel {
        id: mymodel

        ListElement {
            title: "my_name.mp4"
            check: true
            img: "1450465860217s.jpg" //your own img url here
            filesize: "1.5GB"
           lenght: "20:00"
           lastMod: "12/02/2014"
        }

        ListElement {
            title: "my_nam2.mp4"
            check: false
            img: "1450465860217s.jpg" //your own img url here
            filesize: "400MB"
            lenght: "8:00"
            lastMod: "01/01/2015"
        }

        ListElement {
            title: "my_nam2.mp4"
            check: false
            img: "1450465860217s.jpg" //your own img url here
            filesize: "1.5GB"
            lenght: "1:20:00"
            lastMod: "12/13/2016"
       }
    }

TableView {
    width: 1000; height: 500

    anchors.centerIn: parent
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "title"
        title: "Title"
        width: 200
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "filesize"
        title: "FileSize"
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "lenght"
        title: "Lenght"

    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "lastMod"
        title: "Last Modified"
    }


    model: mymodel

    rowDelegate: Rectangle{
        color: "white"
        height: 40
    }

    itemDelegate: RowLayout {
        width: parent == null? 0 : parent.width

        Loader{
            sourceComponent: styleData.column == 0 ?
                             things : null
        }

        Component {
            id: things

            RowLayout{
                height: 30
                CheckBox{
                    id: itemCheckBox
                    checked:  mymodel.get(styleData.row).check
                }

                Image{
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 80
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 40
                    source: mymodel.get(styleData.row).img
                }
            }
        }


        Text {
            //anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: styleData.value
        }
    }
}
}
```

You'll need to code your model in c++ and polish the interface, but its a good starting point.