# Using checkboes in TableView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am creating a `TableView` with custom delegate to have `checkbox`es in the columns and I have had some success with the following:

```
// TableViewCheckBoxColumn.qml
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

TableViewColumn {
    title: ""
    role: "check"
    delegate: CheckBox {
        id: checkBox
    }
}
```

The table implementation is as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Item {
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    ListModel {
        id: testModel
        ListElement {
            check1: true
            check2: true
            check3: false
            check4: false
            check5: false
        }
    }

    TableView {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        TableViewCheckBoxColumn {
            id: checkedColumn1
        }

        TableViewCheckBoxColumn {
            id: checkedColumn2
        }

        TableViewCheckBoxColumn {
            id: checkedColumn3
        }

        TableViewCheckBoxColumn {
            id: checkedColumn4
        }

        TableViewCheckBoxColumn {
            id: checkedColumn5
        }
        model: testModel
    }
}
```

This, at least, creates the `TableView` with the 5 columns with `checkbox`es in each of them. However, I cannot figure out how to propagate the checked statuses of the columns from my `testModel` to the `TableView`.

Comment: there's no need to put the tag in front of the question, that's automatically done by the system and thus discouraged.

Comment: Of course. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first you need to match the role property of the columns with the property of the the model. Then you can access to the value of the property using the property 'styleData. value'

```
ListModel {
    id: testModel

    ListElement {
        check1: true
        check2: true
        check3: false
        check4: false
        check5: false
    }
}


TableView {
    width: 1000; height: 500

    anchors.centerIn: parent
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "check1"

        delegate: CheckBox {
            checked: styleData.value
        }
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "check2"

        delegate: CheckBox {
            checked: styleData.value
        }
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "check3"

        delegate: CheckBox {
            checked: styleData.value
        }
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "check4"

        delegate: CheckBox {
            checked: styleData.value
        }
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "check5"

        delegate: CheckBox {
            checked: styleData.value
        }
    }

    model: testModel
}
```

This is better:

```
TableView {
    width: 1000; height: 500

    anchors.centerIn: parent
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "check1"
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "check2"
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "check3"
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "check4"
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "check5"
    }

    model: testModel

    itemDelegate: CheckBox {
        checked: styleData.value
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this example. What is `setDataInYourModel` and `styleData`? At the moment, I simply want to initialise the initial view as given by my model.

Comment: Ok i thought you had a custom model. Do you really want 5 columns? Or you want a column with 5 rows?

Comment: I was gonna have 5 columns with checkboxes. I figured that I need 5 different definitions of `TableViewColumn` with the `role` set to the corresponding model parameter. I wonder if there is a way to do this without replicating the `TableViewColumn` definition?

Comment: Edited with a proposed solution.

Comment: Yeah, that is basically what I thought that the TableViewColumn needs to be replicated....Would be difficult to create dynamic table schemas in QML?

Comment: Depends. Are you using c++ or just pure QML?

Comment: At the moment pure QML. Quite new to this but a C++/QML mix is not an issue.

Comment: Well, then i recommend to check this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html   You can operate with dynamic models in pure QML but in the end you will need c++ models for real programs.